# How to pivot on two types of aggregations of the same column in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

So I am currently pivoting on a column called 'RESP', but the kicker here is that I need to use both the 'MAX' and 'SUM' aggregate function depending on the ID. How can I go about doing this? I've tried using a CASE statement in my PIVOT statement but was unsuccessful.

Some Sample Data is below:

```
Value        Value_Type         Date            Gender      Age    Name
 83          Income             01-01-19        Male        19     John
 95          Income             01-01-19        Male        19     John
 Civic       Model              01-01-19        Male        19     John
 Blue        Color              01-01-19        Male        19     John
```

I need to pivot so I can receive the following data set:

```
   Date       Gender     Age      Name       Income     Car     Color
  01-01-19    Male       19       John       178        Civic   Blue
```

Below is what I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT value
                     , date
                     , age
                     , name
                     , gender
                  FROM Table
                 PIVOT (
                        CASE WHEN value_Type IN ('Model', 'Color')
                             THEN max(value)
                             WHEN value_type IN ('Income')
                             THEN sum(value)
                              END
                        )
               );
```

Is there any way to use the PIVOT statement to get this? Or will I need to use a conditional MAX(CASE WHEN) and then group/aggregate to get my desired data set?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with `pivot`:

```
select date_, gender, age, name, inc_sm income, mod_mx, col_mx
  from tbl
  pivot (max(value) mx, sum(case value_type when 'Income' then value end) sm
         for value_type in ('Model' mod, 'Color' col, 'Income' inc))
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f2f7ec15d6ae628b52ead5b5944290b1)</sup>**

Answer (score 2):

This looks like conditional aggregation to me:

```
select Date, Gender, Age, Name,
       sum(case when value_type = 'Income' then cast(value as number) end) as income,
       max(case when value_type = 'Model' then value end) as model,
       max(case when value_type = 'Color' then value end) as color
from t
group by Date, Gender, Age, Name;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Gordon, it's always appreciated. I was trying to avoid using the sum/max method. I'm guessing there is no way to use the traditional pivot method?

Comment: @JohnWick . . . There is nothing "traditional" about `pivot`.  It is a bespoke syntax extension available only in Oracle and SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the following query:

```
With DATAA (VALUE, VALUE_TYPE, DATE1, GENDER, AGE, NAME)
AS
(
SELECT '83', 'Income', date '2019-01-01', 'Male', 19, 'John' from dual union all
SELECT '95', 'Income', date '2019-01-01', 'Male', 19, 'John' from dual union all
SELECT 'Civic', 'Model', date '2019-01-01', 'Male', 19, 'John' from dual union all
SELECT 'Blue', 'Color', date '2019-01-01', 'Male', 19, 'John' from dual
)
SELECT
    DATE1,
    GENDER,
    AGE,
    NAME,
    I_INCOME1   AS INCOME,
    M_MODEL1    AS CAR,
    C_COLOR1    AS COLOR
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            VALUE,
            DATE1,
            AGE,
            NAME,
            GENDER,
            VALUE_TYPE
        FROM
            DATAA
    ) PIVOT (
        SUM ( CASE
            WHEN VALUE_TYPE = 'Income' THEN VALUE
        END )
    AS INCOME1, MAX ( CASE
        WHEN VALUE_TYPE = 'Model' THEN VALUE
    END ) AS MODEL1, MAX ( CASE
        WHEN VALUE_TYPE = 'Color' THEN VALUE
    END ) AS COLOR1
        FOR VALUE_TYPE
        IN ( 'Income' AS I, 'Model' AS M, 'Color' AS C )
    );
```

**Output:**

```
DATE1               GEND        AGE NAME     INCOME CAR   COLOR
------------------- ---- ---------- ---- ---------- ----- -----
01-01-2019 12:00:00 Male         19 John        178 Civic Blue
```

Cheers!!